# Could not find module 'SwiftProtobuf' for target 'arm64-apple-tvos'; found: arm64-apple-tvos-simulator, x86_64-apple-tvos-simulator

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing this issue after updating the Xcode 14.2 . I am using Macbook Air M2.

Also I have tried to set Build Active Architecture Only true or false both but didn't work for me.
Any idea about how to fix this issue.